# -Wconversion diagnostic from gcc-trunk when -fsanitize=undefined is passed

Tags: c++, gcc, language-lawyer

This is about the correct diagnostics when `short int`s get promoted during "usual arithmetic conversions". During operation `/` a diagnostic could be reasonably emitted, but during `/=` none should be emitted.

Behaviour for gcc-trunk and clang-trunk seems OK (neither emits diagnostic for first or second case below)... until...

we add the entirely unrelated `-fsanitize=undefined` ... after which, completely bizarrely:

gcc-trunk emits a diagnostic for both cases. **It really shouldn't for the 2nd case, at least.**

Is this a bug in gcc?

[Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/5rbfhY8bW)

[Godbolt link with -O3 - same result](https://godbolt.org/z/aexKEG7zb)

```cpp
int main() {
    short sum   = 50;
    short count = 10;

    // sum and count get promoted to int for the "usual arithmetic conversions"
    // then the assignment could result in a reasonable -Wconversion diagnostic for reduction back
    // to short
    // However clang-trunk and gcc-trunk choose NOT TO issue a diagnostic with -Wconversion enabled
    short avg1 = sum / count;

    // we should be able to prevent promotion to int by using /= assignment operator.
    // Both clang-trunk and gcc-trunk, correctly, DON'T issue a diagnostic with -Wconversion enabled
    auto tmp = sum;
    tmp /= count;
    short avg2 = tmp;

    // HOWEVER if we add -fsanitize=undefined for both compilers
    // then, bizarrly, gcc-trunk issues a diagnostic for both cases above and clang-trunk still for
    // neither

    // none of these ever issue a diagnostic (nor should they)
    tmp += count; // all
    tmp -= count; // are
    tmp *= count; // silent

    return (avg1 + avg2) & 0xff; // prevent "unused" diagnostics
}
```

**EDIT**

Here is the bug I filed for GCC:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=104616

Comment: @user4581301
Yes.. I had it multiplying sum by argc to prevent that earlier.. I can put it back.. it makes no difference

Comment: @user4581301 I have added a second godbolt link with -O3 above. It uses  a workaround with argc to stop it removing the programme... same outcome.

Comment: Groovy. You've got my case covered, so I'll leave this one to the language lawyers to figure out if this is a bug or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a built-in compound assignment operator `$=` the expression `A $= B` behaves identical to an expression `A = A $ B`, except that `A` is evaluated only once. All promotions and other usual arithmetic conversions and converting back to the original type still happen.

Therefore it shouldn't be expected that the warnings differ between `short avg1 = sum / count;` and `tmp /= count;`.

A conversion from `int` to `short` happens in each case. So a conversion warning would be appropriate in either case.

However, [the documentation of GCC warning flags](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html) says specifically that conversions back from arithmetic on small types which are promoted is excluded from the `-Wconversion` flag. GCC offers the `-Warith-conversion` flag to include such cases nonetheless. With it *all* arithmetic in your examples generates a warning.

Also note that this exception to `-Wconversion` has been introduced only with GCC 10. For some more context on it, the bug report from which it was introduced is [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40752).

It seems that Clang has always been more lenient on these cases than GCC. See for example [this issue](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/18959) and [this issue](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/11646).

---

For `/` in GCC `-fsanitize=undefined` seems to break the exception that `-Wconversion` is supposed to have. It seems to me that this is related to the undefined behavior sanitizer adding a null-value check specifically for division. Maybe, after this transformation, the warning flag logic doesn't recognize it as direct arithmetic on the smaller type anymore.

If my understanding of the intended behavior of the warning flags is correct, I would say that this looks unintended and thus is a bug.

Comment: Thanks. I had not found the docs on "don't warn on converting back to a small int", but had suspected as much, so that clears up that part.  My statement about "assignment does not promote" came from here: https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/gctyw5/adding_two_uint16_t_s_without_wconversion_warning/fpu646f/?context=3 . I did not try to find the standard's legalese to prove this, however my reading of this: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Conversions  seems to agree with the statement that these auto promotions only apply to BINARY operators?

Comment: I agree that only  `/` with sanitizer emitting the diagnostic is probably an unintended side effect (AKA bug) of some additional checks by the sanitizer which is disabling the diagnostic "bypass".

Comment: @OliverSchönrock I am either lacking some context or the linked comment is wrong. `i += 42;` does the same conversions as `i = i +42` would. Standard reference: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/expr.ass#6, cppreference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_assignment#Builtin_compound_assignment. Compound assignments are also binary operators.

Comment: Yes, I might have been led down the garden path by that linked statement. I must admit it did seem quite odd that `a = a + b` does something different to `a += b`. So that part of my question may just be based on incorrect information.

Comment: Thanks for link to bug report - reading it now. Yes, I had noticed that gcc < 10 did not suppress/bypass warnings and that fits with my picture of what is going on.. ie they are trying to make -Wconversion actually usuable by making it less noisy about cases which are non-issues.

Comment: These are remarkably confusing to test for. I think I have found another gcc inconsistency for this diagnostic, where, oddly, `+=` and `-=` seem to be silent but `=` emits a diagnostic. I posted the code in an additional answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71183117/1087626

Comment: I notice that that bug report only ever seems to talk about compound assignment operators eg `=+`  with single argument RHS,  and not pure assignments where all of the RHS is also "a small integral type". So does that mean, that event hough the c++ standard makes no difference between `+=` and `=`, gcc -Wconversion DOES after that bug  was committed to gcc-10?

Comment: I have gone ahead and accepted your answer. Thanks for your input. I am going to report the `-fsanitizer` thing as a bug on gcc, once they give me an account and will link that here once done.

Answer (score 0):

supplementary information for discussion under answer by user17732522.

The code below appears to illustrate a case where using `+=` (with single small integer RHS ONLY!) vs `+=` with 2 term binary small integer operation RHS vs simple `=` does help?

gcc emits a -Wconversion diagnostic for the first and third case. Clang emits none.

Why is that? Is this "another inconsistency" in the way gcc emits these diagnostics? Or is the change implemented as a result of [this bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=40752) covering just the narrow case of compound assignment with a single term small integer RHS ?

*Note: this is all without -fsanitizer*

[Updated Godbolt link](https://godbolt.org/z/fhTzKdcvr)

```cpp
int main() {
    short a   = 10;
    short b = 20;

    short sum1 = 30;
    sum1 += b - a;

    short sum2 = 30;
    sum2 += b;
    sum2 -= a;

    short sum3 = 30 + b - a;

    return (sum1 + sum2 + sum3) & 0xff; // prevent "unused" diagnostics
}
```

Comment: I think it covers a single arithmetic operations directly followed by conversion to the smaller type only. For example `short sum3 = b - a;` doesn't produce a warning. I also noticed that Clang actually always less strict on the `-Wconversion` warning than GCC is/was, see edit to my answer.